# log4j-1.2.17.jar Replacement for log4j 2

Tags: log4j, log4j2, talend

I use Talend Open Studio for data integration jobs. TOS still uses log4j-1.2.17.jar and log4j-1.2.16.jar in their out of the box installation for TOS 8.0. Those .jar files are in the install directory under studio\plugins\org.talend.libraries.apache_8.0.1.20211103_1602\lib.  There are other log4j jar files as well for core, api, jcl, jul, log4j-to-slf4j, etc. All of those specific jar files are all using log4j 2 and are relative easy to replace/upgrade to non-vulnerable versions from either the  [maven repository](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.logging.log4j) or the [Talend Nexus Repository Manager](https://talend-update.talend.com/nexus/#nexus-search;quick%7Elog4j).

I have been unable to figure out if it is possible to find a log4j 2 jar that would replace the log4j-1.2.17.jar file.  I've gone to the [the Apache Logging site](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/download.html) and downloaded the apache-log4j-2.20.0-src.zip file and I cannot find a jar file within that 28mb 6,000 file download either.

I'm not an application developer. I just use software for data integration jobs that puts this log4j-1.2.17.jar file everywhere that I deploy a Talend program and our security scans flag this as a level 10 vulnerability that is a problem for PCI compliance.

Is there a log4j 2 replacement for this log4j-1.2.17.jar file that would be in the Log4j 2.17.1 range that would no longer be flagged for either CVE-2021-45105, CVE-2021-44832 or being obsolete as log4j 1 is?